# Is the Fréchet derivative of a measurable function measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, frechet-derivative

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $E,F$ be $\mathbb R$-Banach spaces
- $f:\Omega\times E\to F$ such that $f(\;\cdot\;,x)$ is strongly $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(E))$-measurable for all $x\in E$ and $f(\omega,\;\cdot\;)\in C^1(E;F)$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$

Are we able to show the the Fréchet derivative ${\rm D}f(\;\cdot\;,x)$ of $f$ at $x\in E$ is strongly $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(\mathfrak L(E,F)))$-measurable?

The claim is obviously true for the classical derivative in the case $E=F=\mathbb R$, since then ${\rm D}f(\;\cdot\;,x)$ is the limit of the measurable differentiation quotients.

Comment: You are assuming $f$ is of class $\mathscr{C}^1,$ so $\mathbf{D}f$ is continuous. Is this of help?

Comment: @WillM. ${\rm D}f:\Omega\times E\to\mathfrak L(E,F)$ is continuous with respect to the *second* variable. The question is about measurability in the *first* variable.

Comment: Meanwhile I've observed that, since $f(\omega,\;\cdot\;)$ is Gâteaux differentiable for all $\omega\in\Omega$, we can at least show that ${\rm D}f(\;\cdot\;,x)y$ is $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B(F))$-measurable for all $x,y\in E$.

Comment: So, you are fixing $x \in \mathrm{E}$ and then considering the mapping $\omega \mapsto \mathbf{D}f(\omega, x)$ from $\Omega$ into $\mathscr{L}(\mathrm{E}; \mathrm{F}).$ I would suspect that this is not true in general, though it will always be true when $\mathrm{E} = \Bbb R$ since you can identify canonically $\mathbf{D}f( \cdot, x)$ as a limit of Leibniz's quotients. Probably, when $\mathrm{E}$ is the Euclidean space of dimension $d$ you can apply partial derivatives, and get measurability again (I haven't done the details). But for general $\mathrm{E}$ it is probably false.

Comment: For instance, when $\mathrm{E}$ is $\Bbb R^d$ and $\mathrm{pr}_k$ the $k$th canonical projection $\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R,$ then $\mathbf{D}f(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^d \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} \circ \mathrm{pr}_k$ and maybe you can show each thing in the right hand side are measurable.